# natbib does not sort&compress

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, sorting

I have an article in which I am using natbib with `sort&compress` option, but it does not seem to work

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Introduction text \citet{J2009,J2013,J2016}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

and this is the references file

```
% filename references.bib

@Article{J2016,
  author  = {Jappo, P.M.},
  title   = {Title1},
  journal = {Mech. Res. Commun.},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {X},
  pages   = {1--2},
}

@Article{J2013,
  author  = {Jappo, P.M.},
  title   = {Title2},
  journal = {Phys. Lett. A},
  year    = {2013},
  volume  = {X},
  pages   = {1--2},
}

@Article{J2009,
  author  = {Jappo, P.M.},
  title   = {Title3},
  journal = {Math. Comput. Simul},
  year    = {2009},
  volume  = {X},
  pages   = {1--2},
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `unsrtnat` supports sorting? As far as I understand is that an *un*sorted style.

Comment: @TeXnician: thank you for your comment. I have the same problem with `plainnat`, or should I use yet another style?

Comment: I add that the sorting works, is the compress that doesn't work (I expect [1-3] and not [1,2,3]).

Comment: Use `\cite{J2009,J2013,J2016}` instead of `\citet{J2009,J2013,J2016}` (see missing `t`).

Comment: @TeXnician: `unsrtnat` does not sort the references, but if you have `\cite{J2009,J2013,J2016}` and `\cite{J2013,J2016,J2009}` in one example, you will see that `natbib` with `sort&compress` still sorts the cites.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`natbib` is not able to sort `\citet` cites, because it sorts and compresses only number sequences. It does not test, whether or not the names are same, before it compresses the number sequences. So only `\cite` or `\citep` can be compressed.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Introduction text \cite{J2009,J2013,J2016}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The documentation of `natbib` indeed is somehow misleading.

If you know that the authors are same, you could use

```
Introduction text \citeauthor{J2009} \cite{J2009,J2013,J2016}.
```

to get

[image]

but I would call this only a work around, not a solution.

A real solution would be to switch to [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with [`biber`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber). You can use option `natbib`, if you do not like to change all the `\citet` in your existing document:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
% filename references.bib

@Article{J2016,
  author  = {Jappo, P.M.},
  title   = {Title1},
  journal = {Mech. Res. Commun.},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {X},
  pages   = {1--2},
}

@Article{J2013,
  author  = {Jappo, P.M.},
  title   = {Title2},
  journal = {Phys. Lett. A},
  year    = {2013},
  volume  = {X},
  pages   = {1--2},
}

@Article{J2009,
  author  = {Jappo, P.M.},
  title   = {Title3},
  journal = {Math. Comput. Simul},
  year    = {2009},
  volume  = {X},
  pages   = {1--2},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sortcites,natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Introduction text \citet{J2009,J2013,J2016}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: biblatex solution]

Comment: Thank you, but with `\cite` I obtain `[1-3]` and not `Jappo [1-3]`, so I think `\citet` makes sense.

Comment: Nevertheless, `natbib` does not compress `\citet`.

Comment: I've added a solution using `biblatex` that provides automatic sorting and compression.